# Unable to set the IncludeBorder property of the Style class

Tags: excel, vba, styles, border

Googling, I found the next code to copy just the borders on an Excel spreadsheet.
But when I run it, it gets the next error on the first line:

> "Run-time error '1004':
>   Unable to set the IncludeBorder property of the Style class"

I tried to put it else where before that sub, but it still appears the same error. My sheet is activate and not locked.

```
Sub copyBorders(lRow As Long, LetCol As String)

   ActiveWorkbook.Styles("Normal").IncludeBorder = False

   Range("B4:B" & lRow & "").Copy
      With Range("" & ColLetter(lCol - 1) & "4:" & ColLetter(lCol - 1) & "" & lRow & "").Offset(20)
        .PasteSpecial -4122
        .Style = "Normal"
       End With

   ActiveWorkbook.Styles("Normal").IncludeBorder = True
End Sub
```

I expect to run normally, because can't find which can be the error.

Comment: Hm, can't reproduce the error with this code.

Comment: Yeah, it also runs in another workbook. :( But not in the one that i'm interested in.

Comment: The source of the problem must be elsewhere then. Hard to diagnose a problem you can't reproduce reliably... see if you can't come up with a proper [mcve].